# Hide coordinates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to hide the coordinates in a grid in matplotlib (see code below). Unfortunately no matter which way I try it only the bottom right position gets hidden. All other coordinates/axes are still being displayed. Would be wonderful if someone could help me with that since I do not know what else to try right now.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fig,ax = plt.subplots(6,7)
plt.axis('off')

filenames=['gelb.png'.format(i) for i in range(42)]
for i in range(42):
    #plt.axis('off')
    with open(filenames[i],'rb') as f:
        image=Image.open(f)
        ax[i%6][i//6].imshow(image)
fig.show()
```

Comment: is it possible to attach the image file or a screenshot of your result and what yo want to change? I see you are opening an image so I dont know what coordinates you wish to hide

Comment: You probably want `['gelb{:02d}.png'.format(i) for i in range(42)]`

Comment: I have posted an answer, even if I'm not totally sure of the meaning  of your question... could you please confirm that my post does indeed answer your question? otherwise I'd prefer to delete my answer. Thank you in advance.